# SOA model Schema parsing error for complex types

Tags: java, parsing, xsd

The schema parser is able to parse the ComplexTypes of form:

```
<xsd:complexType name="PersonType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="firstName" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="lastName" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="address" type="tns:AddressType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

But it is not able to parse the ComplexTypes of form:

```
<xsd:element name="PersonType">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="firstName" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="lastName" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="address" type="tns:AddressType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

In the later form it considers "PersonType" to be just an Element and not ComplexType. Hence the elements included in it are not parsed at all. Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today so I thought to see what SOAP-UI has to say about this when providing the wsdl file that has similar contents as the second image,
it showed them as Anonymous Complex Types yet have no solution for them, one thought can be to use the elements separately outside complexType tags.
Also anonymous types are not preferred. Probably the below link can help :
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-avoid-anonymous-types/ws-avoid-anonymous-types-pdf.pdf

Comment: Links will decay over time. Please edit your answer with proper information.